# How to define a method and attribute to my appended div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, constructor, initialization

I have DIVs dynamically appended to the DOM. I want each of them to have some method, like when I click a button inside the div, the div will be removed from the DOM; and some attributes that I can read from.

So I figure I need an object, but this is what confuses me:

```
var block = tmpl('added_video_thumb', data);
$('#wrapper').append(block);
```

I want the block to be the object, so I did this:

```
var blocks = function(id, data){
  this.block = tmpl('added_video_thumb', data);
}
```

And I changed the code to this:

```
var block = new blocks('added_video_thumb', data);
$('#wrapper').append(block);
```

Then I don't know how to define the method, I don't want to call a function like:

```
$('#delete').click(function(){
  block.remove();
})
```

What I want is when I do this:

```
var block = new blocks();
```

It takes care of everything. Please help me construct this blocks object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem, it is that you want to dynamically create an element and assign methods to it's own children.

**HTML**

```
<button id="add">Add</button>
<div class="container">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function addBlock() {

var div = $( '<div class="inner_div">
                 <button class="delete">Delete</button>
              </div>' );

div.children('button.delete').on( 'click', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});


$('.container').append(div);
}
```

Example on fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/wyXxn/1/
​

Comment: yeah,i guess i was confuse about var a = function(){} and var a = {}

Answer (score 1):

You can check the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rrsmh/2/)

**HTML Code**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="ID" id="id-input" />
<input type="text" placeholder="data" id="data-input" />
<button id="add-div">Add Div</button>

<div id="wrapper">

</div>​
```

**JS Code**

```
$(function(){
    var block = function(id, data) {
        this.id = id;
        this.data = data;
        $("#wrapper").append('<div id="' + id + '">'+ data +'<br /> <button id="del-' + id + '">Delete Me!</button> </div>');
        $("#del-"+id).click(function() {
            $("#"+id).remove();

        });
    }

    $("#add-div").click(function() {
      var newBlock = new block($("#id-input").val(), $("#data-input").val());
    });

});​
```